# Why does flexbox not center my image?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

```
section
{
background-color: #EEEEEE;
margin: 10vmin 5vmin;
padding: 2vmin;
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
flex-flow: column wrap;  
}

img
{
height: 30vmax;
border: 1vmin solid black;
border-radius: 30vmax;
margin: 1vmin;
}
```

Entire source code available here : https://codepen.io/de_arth/pen/dvLoyO/

Basically, I'm able to center everything BUT an image, (and a link in the very last section) with flexbox, even though it should be in a single straight line on mobile and desktop displays. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try adding "text-align:center;" to the section.

Comment: Simply add text-align: center  like so https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XgYzYb

Comment: Alternatively, add `flex-direction: column;` to `section` and remove `flex-flow: column wrap;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code work as is, though there is a *invisible/invalid* space character in front of these 3 lines

```
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
```

Here is an [updated codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KqeZZz) with the same code you already have, where I rewrote those 3 lines

And here is a Stack snippet

```css
body
{
  background-color: #FAFAFA;
}

section
{
  background-color: #EEEEEE;
  margin: 10vmin 5vmin;
  padding: 2vmin;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-flow: column wrap;  
}

img
{
  height: 30vmax;
  border: 1vmin solid black;
  border-radius: 30vmax;
  margin: 1vmin;
}

h1, h2
{
  margin: 2vmin;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 5vmin;
}

h1
{
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size: 8vw;
}

h2
{
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  font-size: 3vw;
  font-style: italic;
}

h3
{
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size: 4vw;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 4vw;
}

p
{
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  font-size: 3vw;  
  text-align: center;
}

a
{
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  margin-top: 30vmin;
  text-align: center;
}

#awards > p
{
  line-height: 7vw;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 40.5em)
{
  
  section
  {
    height: 100vh;
  }
  
  h1
  {
    font-size: 5vw;
  }
  
  h2
  {
    font-size: 3vw;
  }
  
  h3
  {
    font-size: 3vw;
    margin-top: 1vw;
    margin-bottom: 0;
  }
  
  p
  {
    font-size: 2vw;
    line-height: 2.5vw;
    margin: 0;
  }
  
  #awards > p
  {
    line-height: 4vw;
  }
  
  a
  {
    margin-top: 2vw;
    font-size: 3vw;
  }
  
  section:not(#intro) > h1
  {
    margin: 1vw;
  }
  
  section:not(#intro) > div
  {
    margin: 1vw;
  }
  
  footer > p
  {
    margin-bottom: 1vw;
  }
    
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:300|Roboto" rel="stylesheet">  
</head>

<section id = "intro">
  <img src = "https://assets.kennislink.nl/system/files/000/134/321/large/Richard_Feynman_Nobel.jpg?1494968180">
  <div>
    <h1> Richard Feynman </h1>
    <h2> Physicist. Prankster. Genius. </h2>
  </div>
</section>

<section id = "early">
  <h1> Early Life </h1>
  <div>
    <h3> 1918 </h3>
    <p> Born in Queens, New York. </p>
    <h3> 1933 </h3>
    <p> Teaches himself trigonometry, advanced algebra, infinite series, analytic geometry and calculus. </p>
    <h3> 1939 </h3>
    <p> Obtains his B.Sc from the Massachusetts Institute of Technology. </p>
    <h3> 1942 </h3>
    <p> Obtains his PhD from Princeton University. Marries Arline Greenbaum. </h3>
  </div>
</section>

<section id = "bomb">
  <h1> Manhattan Project </h1>
  <div>
    <h3> 1942 </h3>
    <p> Recruited into the project by R R Wilson. </p>
    <h3> 1943 </h3>
    <p> Redloyed at Los Alamos Laboratory, in New Mexico and made group leader.</p>
    <h3> 1945 </h3>
    <p> First wife dies of Tuberculosis. Becomes the only person to see the explosion at the Trinity Nuclear Test without any protection. </p>
  </div>
</section>

<section id = "later">
  <h1> Cornell </h1>
  <div>
    <h3> 1945 </h3>
    <p> Hired as Professor of Theoretical Physics at Cornell University. </p>
    <h3> 1946 </h3>
    <p> Feigns mental illness to avoid being drafted, and later suffers from depression as his father dies. Solves less practical problems due to lack of focus.  </p>
    <h3> 1948 </h3>
    <p> Delivers his first presentation involving Feynman diagrams, and is met with many objections. </p>
    <h3> 1950 </h3>
    <p> Papers citing the Feynman diagrams soon become prevalent, as a tool of unprecedented power. </p>
  </div>
</section>

<section id = "caltech">
  <h1> Caltech </h1>
  <div>
    <h3> 1952 </h3>
    <p> Appointed Professor of Theoretical Physics at California Institute of Technology. Marries Mary Louise Bell. </p>
    <h3> 1958 </h3>
    <p> A divorce is final after a stormy marriage, on the grounds of extreme cruelty. </p>
    <h3> 1960 </h3>
    <p> Marries Gweneth Howarth. Carl was born in 1962, and Michelle was adopted in 1968. </p>
    <h3> 1988 </h3>
    <p> Dies following kidney failure, after a decade long battle with cancer. </p>
  </div>
</section>
  
<section id = "awards">
  <h1> Awards </h1>
  <p> Albert Einstein Award - 1954 <br> Ernest Orlando Lawrence Award - 1962 <br> The Nobel Prize in Physics - 1965 <br> Oersted Medal - 1972 <br> National Medal of Science - 1979 </p>
  <a href = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richard_Feynman"> Read more on Wikipedia </a>
</section>

<footer>
  <p> Designed and compiled by Arvind S </p>
</footer>
```

Comment: Thankyou! Upvoted and marked as answer. But do you have any idea as to why this happened and how I can avoid it?

Comment: @Arvind Sometimes when one copy code from somewhere, this can happen, so when one **know** a certain code fragment should work, these stuff, along with misspelled words and missed out characters is the first thing to check ... and I myself have done these mistakes thousands of times :)

Answer (score 0):

Add `text-align:center`

```
section {
    background-color: #eeeeee;
    flex-flow: column wrap;
    margin: 10vmin 5vmin;
    padding: 2vmin;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: That worked. Follow up question, why does text-align work on an image?

Comment: This answer doesn't explain why Flexbox doesn't center the image

Answer (score 0):

you need to add `text-align`

set `text-align:center` in your css `section` part

**for ex:**

```
section
{
background-color: #EEEEEE;
margin: 10vmin 5vmin;
padding: 2vmin;
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
flex-flow: column wrap;  
text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: but its work using this so why its not usefull for you

Comment: If you check my answer you'll see yours is redundant and doesn't address the real problem. Flexbox doesn't need `text-align: center` and this works only because it doesn't have the same flaw the already existing code base have